# Pausing my App without stopping Display

Tags: multithreading, sleep, thread-sleep

Im trying to let my App wait for 5 seconds. But it doesnt matter if I use sleep() or wait() in my created thread, My screen always gets white and after the 5 seconds it does what it should. How can I let the App wait without pausing the screendisplaying.

Comment: By app do you mean IOS app, C++ application, can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

You should think about implementing some sort of timer, instead of sleep or wait. This will allow rendering and other things to continue while your timer completes.

Tutorial here:
[CountDown Timer ios tutorial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17145112/countdown-timer-ios-tutorial)