# How to invalidate NSTimer in iOS application correctly?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I am new in ios application development. I want to set countdown timer of 30 min in my application so I had put this code in my application it is working but in below code it will continue start from 30 minutes again and again and again. I want to exit that exam page on completing 30 minutes so how can I do this can any one help me please  .

thank you

[CountDown Timer ios tutorial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17145112/countdown-timer-ios-tutorial/17147585#17147585)

Comment: that examples predates arc - call invalidate like said in the comments

Comment: possible duplicate of [CountDown Timer ios tutorial?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17145112/countdown-timer-ios-tutorial)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you does not need to add Timer for this task.

You can simple call your method like :

```
[self performSelector:@selector(yourMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:1800];
```

Now it will call your method after 30 minutes or say 1800 seconds.

Comment: thanks for helping me.. it is really work thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Remove this `secondsLeft = 16925;` from `updateCounter`.

```
- (void)updateCounter:(NSTimer *)theTimer {
    if(secondsLeft > 0 ){
        secondsLeft -- ;
        hours = secondsLeft / 3600;
        minutes = (secondsLeft % 3600) / 60;
        seconds = (secondsLeft %3600) % 60;
        myCounterLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds];
    }
    else{
        if(timer != nil)
        {
            [timer invalidate];
            timer = nil;
        }
        //Write the code to exit your exam page
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: it move's towered end test in less than one second i mean instantly moves in end test.

Comment: You just asked what to do, Customize it in your way. :)