# NSTimer countdown tick

Tags: ios, nstimer

Please excuse my english, I'm not very fluent.

I have an application with 10 workouts, and i would like to give to each workout an amount of time, for ex :
1st workout : 30 seconds
2nd workout : 40 seconds

But for now, i only managed to give each workout the same amount of seconds for all workout..

This is what i used to work this :

```
#define EXERCISELENGTH 30
#define EXERCISELENGTH1 40
#define RESTLENGTH 10

- (void)tick
{
if (self.inCountdown && (countdown == 0)) {
    self.inCountdown = NO;
    self.inExercise = YES;
    countdown = EXERCISELENGTH;
    [self workoutUI];
    [self updateUI];
    workoutIndex++;
}

if (self.inExercise && (countdown == 0)) {
    self.inExercise = NO;
    self.inRest = YES;
    countdown = RESTLENGTH;
    [self restUI];
    [self updateUI];
}
if (self.inRest && (countdown == 0)) {
    self.inRest = NO;
    self.inExercise = YES;
    countdown = EXERCISELENGTH;
    [self workoutUI];
    [self updateUI];
    workoutIndex++;
    if (workoutIndex == 10) {
        [self doneUI];
        [self.timer invalidate];
        return;
    }
}
[self updateUI];
countdown--;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: so you want to run the timer for all workouts all at once?

Comment: No, i want to run timer for 30 seconds for the first workout, then 10 seconds for rest, than 40 seconds for the second workout ect...

Answer (score 0):

you have many options:

If you want to call a workout method every 30 seconds, you use this:

```
  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30.0
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(workoutMethod)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];
```

If you want to call the workout method after 30 seconds, you use this:

```
 [self performSelector:@selector(workoutMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:30.0];
```

If you want to start a countdown timer after you start the workout method, you use this example : [CountDown Timer ios tutorial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17145112/countdown-timer-ios-tutorial)

Comment: I have already done that.. what i want to do is give each workout a specific amount of time.

Comment: Well, Im confsed. What do you mean by giving each workout a specific amount of time? HOw is it different than running a count down timer after the workout starts ?

Comment: this is what happens with my current code :
Workout 1 : 30 seconds 
Workout 2 : 30 seconds
Workout 3 : 30 seconds 

But what i want to do is : 
Workout 1 : 20 seconds 
Workout 2 : 30 seconds 
Workout 3 : 40 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a countdown timer, you should set up a repeating `NSTimer` that triggers an action that updates the display every second or so. However, that action should calculate the time remaining using the system time. So, your code should:

- get the current time and calculate the expected finish time according to the desired time period (20 sec, 30 sec, etc.)
- start a repeating timer with a 1 sec interval

Your timer's action should:

- get the current system time
- compare to the expected finish time
- update the display
- invalidate itself if it has reached the finish time

What you *don't* want to do is to rely on the timer to trigger at exactly 1 second intervals. `NSTimer`'s resolution is such that each 'tick' can be off by as much as 0.1 sec, which means that 30 ticks could be off by up to 3 seconds. Using the system time, e.g. `CACurrentMediaTime()`, will provide a much more accurate clock and avoid accumulation of error.